# How to prevent XSS when loading data into div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I'm fetching data with Ajax (JSON) parsing that then into a template like this:

```
function noteTemplate(obj) {
    var date = obj.created_at.split(/[- :]/),
        dateTime = date[2] + '.' + date[1] + '.' + date[0];
        dateTime += ' @ ' + date[3] + ':' + date[4] + ':' + date[5];

    var note = '<div class="note-container" target="' + obj.id + '">';
        note += '<div class="note-options"><div class="note-remove"></div></div>';
        note += '<div class="note-name">' + obj.name + '</div>';
        note += '<div class="note-date">' + dateTime + '</div>';
        note += '<div class="note-content">' + obj.content + '</div>';
        note += '</div>';
    return note;
}
```

And then appending that to a div using jQuery. Now if `obj.name` or `obj.content` contains any JS, those will be executed.

What would be the most proper way to prevent that? Thanks

**Update:**

I found a solution and in native way by escaping < > and replacing them with entities like this does the job.

```
obj.content.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
```

jQuery:

```
var $note = $(note);
$note.find('.note-name').text(obj.name);
$note.find('.note-content').text(obj.content);

return $note;
```

**.text() sanitazes it for you.**

Thanks to @Rory McCrossan for the idea!

Comment: I found a solution, althought not sure if that's proper but escaping < > does the job: obj.content.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;")

Answer (score 3):

The issue would be how you append the HTML the function returns to the DOM, not how you generate the HTML itself.

If you append the content of the element using jQuery's `text()` method it will be sanitised for you, something like this:

```
$('#myElement').text(noteTemplate(data));
```

Comment: Hey thanks! The issue though is that I'm appending, prepending thus text wouldn't be quite valid here as there are multiple elements and that would overwrite the root.

Comment: In which case you'd need to create a container then set the `text()` of that with the HTML generated from the `noteTemplate()` function.

Comment: That would work as well yeah, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to :)